# Crystal Reports Visual Studio Report Does Not Change

Tags: crystal-reports

Just when I thought I've seen all the problems that could happen....
Crystal Reports Visual Studio 2013.  A launcher program (vb.net)  creates the database tables used in the Report (rpt).  I select customer ! and get the report.  I select another customer, get customer 1.  It doesn't matter what I select, the report is the same.  The database (Views) is correct.  So I moved the application to another computer.  I get the report from customer 1, even though that customer data is not on that computer.  Is something building the results of the report into the code?  Has anyone seen anything like that?

Program Flow:

```
   * delete Report Title view file if exists.
     - create Report Title view
  * delete Base data view file if exists.
    - create Base data view
  * delete Details view file if exists.
    - create Details view from information in Base data view
```

I'm suspecting that the application is instructing SQL Server to perform the Delete and Create tasks serially, however SQL Server is not processing them in serial but in multi-task mode. My other reports which are more simple in creating Views, are working fine.

Let me know if you need additional information.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So. here is what I found.
  I hired someone to help create the new Report. In the Crystal Report editor, in the Main Report Preview tab, is a checkbox (Save data in the report.) He checked this box while testing.  (I didn't know it existed).

When developing a report this is useful as you can preview the changes without having to run the entire program. CR will log into the database and capture the last table views you ran.  But, when you build the application, you must remember to un-check this option (again in the editor, Preview tab.

Pheww.  That was 4 days of trouble-shooting.  I hope this helps others using Crystal Reports.